# What do the charactors " '/2' " mean in the variable declaration?

Tags: variables

I'm working on an RS485 project, In the CPP file there are `const` variables declared in the following manner:

```
#include <RS485_protocol.h>
const byte STX = '\2'; 
const byte ETX = '\3';
```

What does the '\2' and '\3' mean?

Answer (score 1):

The '\2' and '\3' are characters with octal code 2 and 3. Which is nothing more then 2 and 3 in octal and in decimal. The author could simply write `const byte STX = 2; const byte ETX = 3;`.

Characters with ASCII code 2 and 3 are control characters STX (start of text) and ETX (end of text). Control characters are invisible characters used to control the terminal or as mark characters in communication.

Comment: Perhaps the question is more about the '\' than the 2 and 3. A list is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape